# Can we call JavaScript as platform independent language?

Tags: javascript, platform-independent

I searched it on the internet and it says

> JavaScript is a simple programming language built into Netscape 2.0 and greater. ... Since the JavaScript interpreter is part of Netscape, it is platform-independent

But if JavaScript platform independent, why does some functionalities work on one browser, but not on the other. It is many times mentioned in the documentation also that this works in the following browser.

Comment: Yup there are multiple platform so there are multiple implementations.

Comment: You've mixed JS and DOM (environment) methods/properties. JS in modern browsers is practically exactly the same language. Of course the language is evolving, and old browsers (or environments) don't support new features.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is realization of the EcmaScript specification.

JavaScript in different browsers has different engines, i.e. implementations. Server-side JavaScript runs on modified Chrome's engine.

What you talking about is the APIs. Filesystem API is NodeJS-specific, DOM-api is specific to browsers. Even [`console.log` is not the part of JavaScript spec](https://medium.com/swlh/console-log-isnt-in-the-javascript-language-2b0f24d57397), but part of the implementation :)

Also there is an [implementations for IoT](https://jerryscript.net/)

So I think we can say that JS is platform independent.

Comment: Also, for completeness - [Netscape announced JS as cross-platform language](https://web.archive.org/web/20020606002913/http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/pr/newsrelease67.html) back in 1995. It does also say it's "complementary to and integrated with Java" which...isn't exactly true but the cross-platform is.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a lightweight scripting language based on **ECMAScript** standards. It executes on the browser and therefore reduces the load on the server. Any **JavaScript-enabled browser** can understand and interpreted JavaScript code which simply means that you can simply write the script once and run it anywhere and anytime.

Different browsers using different engines to run JavaScripts i.e Chromes' V8, Firefox's SpiderMonkey, Edge's Chakra. In general, you can write your JavaScript applications and run them on any platform or any browser without affecting the output of the Script. Any JavaScript code is executed on different types of hardware a JavaScript program written for.

So wean call it as a **platform independent** or **portable**.